# Почему не импортируется gsap?

Tags: javascript, gsap

Я установил **gsap** через **npm**:

> npm install gsap

Потом захотел импортнуть его в проект:

```
import { TimelineMax } from 'gsap'

const tl = new TimelineMax();

tl.to("img", 0.5, {opacity: 1});
```

Но в консоли вывелась ошибка:

> Unexpected token '{'. import call expects exactly one argument.

Я перепробовал все синтаксисы, не получается(

ЧТО делать?

Comment: `import { TimelineMax } from 'gsap'` ?

Comment: Не работает блин

Comment: `import TimelineMax  from 'gsap'`;

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica так не будет работать.

Comment: Нет опять тоже ошибка

Comment: `const gsap = require('gsap');`

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов тогда `import * as TimelineMax from 'gsap'` :D

Comment: У тебя проблема с каким то  импортом другого компонента

Comment: А как будет работать?

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica так точно будет работать )

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов теперь unexpeted "*"

Comment: @user370651 покажи весь код.И не надо тут материться

Comment: Это не мат, а звездочка и это весь js

Comment: @user370651 покажите, как скрипт этот подключаете.

Comment: Нет это не весь js.Смотри самый простой код который я сварганил за пять минут https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-northcutt-m3in6 все окей работает как часы.Где то у тебя опечатка это точно.Смотри повнимательней

Comment: `<script src="script.js"></script>`.

Comment: @user370651 попробуйте `<script src="script.js" type="module"></script>`.

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов я конечно знаю что я не внимательный но я не настолько лошпет чтобы в 3 строках не найти но попробую вглядеться раз вы говорите

Comment: @SuvitrufsaysReinstateMonica нет не работает

Comment: @ИзбытокСусликов так в том и дело что в песочницах все работает я уже проверял а у меня в браузере нет

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
import gsap from "gsap";

gsap.set("img", { opacity: 0 });
gsap.to("img", { duration: 2, opacity: 0.5 });
```